# unable to POST data after reading file uploaded by user on a web page

Tags: javascript, post

I am trying to read an uploaded file via JS and then publish its content on to another page using the POST method

HTML file:

```
<div class="sm2 ">
    <label for="file" class="control-label">Upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" multiple="multiple" id="myfile">
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
var $i = $('#myfile');
input = $i[0];
if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
    myfile = input.files[0];
    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function()  { alert(fr.result); };
    fr.readAsText( myfile );
    }
else {
    alert("File not selected")
    }
$.post("/dc/ajax",
        {
            action: "load_mob1",
            data:fr.result
            contentType: false,
         },
```

I think the POST method is called before the file is read. How do i wait for the file to be read before POST is being called?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `fr.readAsText` is asynchronous, you need to wait for `fr.onload` to complete before `fr.result` has any content

```
var $i = $('#myfile');
input = $i[0];
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    myfile = input.files[0];
    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
        $.post("/dc/ajax", {
            action: "load_mob1",
            data: fr.result
            contentType: false,
        });
        fr.readAsText(myfile);
    };
} else {
    alert("File not selected")
}
```

This also prevents what would happen now, the $.post would be run even when no file was selected

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the post method inside the fr.onload method where you have the result alerting.